# find vs find_by vs where

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, dynamic-finders

I am new to rails. What I see that there are a lot of ways to find a record:

1. `find_by_<columnname>(<columnvalue>)`
2. `find(:first, :conditions => { <columnname> => <columnvalue> }`
3. `where(<columnname> => <columnvalue>).first`

And it looks like all of them end up generating exactly the same SQL. Also, I believe the same is true for finding multiple records:

1. `find_all_by_<columnname>(<columnvalue>)`
2. `find(:all, :conditions => { <columnname> => <columnvalue> }`
3. `where(<columnname> => <columnvalue>)`

Is there a rule of thumb or recommendation on which one to use?

Answer (score 137, accepted):

**Edit:**
This answer is very old and other, better answers have come up since this post was made.  I'd advise looking at the one posted below by @Hossam Khamis for more details.

Use whichever one you feel suits your needs best.

The `find` method is usually used to retrieve a row by ID:

```
Model.find(1)
```

It's worth noting that `find` will throw an exception if the item is not found by the attribute that you supply.  Use `where` (as described below, which will return an empty array if the attribute is not found) to avoid an exception being thrown.

Other uses of `find` are usually replaced with things like this:

```
Model.all
Model.first
```

`find_by` is used as a helper when you're searching for information within a column, and it maps to such with naming conventions.  For instance, if you have a column named `name` in your database, you'd use the following syntax:

```
Model.find_by(name: "Bob")
```

`.where` is more of a catch all that lets you use a bit more complex logic for when the conventional helpers won't do, and it returns an array of items that match your conditions (or an empty array otherwise).

Comment: `find_by` is not deprecated, but the syntax is changing a bit. From `find_by_name("Bob")` to `find_by(:name, "Bob")`.

Comment: @BrianMorearty I believe you meant `find_by(name: "Bob")`

Comment: @BrianMorearty I couldn't find any evidence of `find_by_...` being deprecated, do you have a source? It seems `find_by` and `find_by_...` are both still supported in Rails 4.

Comment: @Dennis, you are correct that it's not deprecated, and that's what I said. But I could have been more clear when I said "but the syntax is changing a bit." What I meant was, "but a new syntax is available now as well." See MCB's correction for the new syntax.

Comment: This is what mentioned in the rails 4.0 release "All dynamic methods except for find_by_... and find_by_...! are deprecated" more details of http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html#active-record-deprecations

Comment: While its not worth a downvote, I believe other answers are better qualifiers for an accepted answer. @hossam-khamis answer below includes very relevant information, which demonstrates that the use cases for these three types of queries are quite different. Its especially important to note that `#find` will raise while `#where` can return an empty Array/Relation.

Comment: Would be great to add the last note (Edit) to the first line of the post. THanks

Answer (score 156):

**where** returns ActiveRecord::Relation

Now take a look at find_by implementation:

```
def find_by
  where(*args).take
end
```

As you can see **find_by** is the same as **where** but it returns only one record. This method should be used for getting 1 record and **where** should be used for getting all records with some conditions.

Comment: find_by returns an object, yet where returns a collection.

Comment: When query value out of range, `find_by` will  rescue `::RangeError` from `where(*args)`  and return nil.

Answer (score 74):

**`Model.find`**

1- Parameter: ID of the object to find.

2- If found: It returns the object (One object only).

3- If not found: raises an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception.

**`Model.find_by`**

1- Parameter: key/value

Example:

```
User.find_by name: 'John', email: 'john@doe.com'
```

2- If found: It returns the object.

3- If not found: returns `nil`.

***Note:*** If you want it to raise `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` use `find_by!`

**`Model.where`**

1- Parameter: same as `find_by`

2- If found: It returns `ActiveRecord::Relation` containing one or more records matching the parameters.

3- If not found: It return an Empty `ActiveRecord::Relation`.

Answer (score 37):

There is a difference between `find` and `find_by` in that `find` will return an error if not found, whereas `find_by` will return null.

Sometimes it is easier to read if you have a method like `find_by email: "haha"`, as opposed to `.where(email: some_params).first`.

Answer (score 18):

Since Rails 4 you can do:

```
User.find_by(name: 'Bob')
```

which is the equivalent `find_by_name` in Rails 3.

Use `#where` when `#find` and `#find_by` are not enough.

Comment: Agis, I agree with you but I've been searching over the internet that why should we use `find_by` and not `find_by_<column_name>`. I need it to answer someone.

Comment: Agis, do you have any sources to back up your claim that we should no longer be using `find_by_name` in Rails 4? As far as I know, [it's not been deprecated](https://github.com/rails/activerecord-deprecated_finders).

Comment: Is there a simple way to do that but say the name has a wildcard in it so something like `find_by(name: "Rob*")`

Comment: @Dennis It's possible to use both, they are valid. I prefer the new syntax since the API is more intuitive IMHO. It's how I would design it myself :)

Answer (score 8):

The accepted answer generally covers it all, but I'd like to add something, 
just incase you are planning to work with the model in a way like updating, and you are retrieving a single record(whose `id` you do not know), Then `find_by` is the way to go, because it retrieves the record and does not put it in an array

```
irb(main):037:0> @kit = Kit.find_by(number: "3456")
  Kit Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "kits".* FROM "kits" WHERE "kits"."number" = 
 '3456' LIMIT 1
=> #<Kit id: 1, number: "3456", created_at: "2015-05-12 06:10:56",   
updated_at: "2015-05-12 06:10:56", job_id: nil>

irb(main):038:0> @kit.update(job_id: 2)
(0.2ms)  BEGIN Kit Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "kits" WHERE  
("kits"."number" = '3456' AND "kits"."id" != 1) LIMIT 1 SQL (0.5ms)   
UPDATE "kits" SET "job_id" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE  "kits"."id" = 
1  [["job_id", 2], ["updated_at", Tue, 12 May 2015 07:16:58 UTC +00:00]] 
(0.6ms)  COMMIT => true
```

but if you use `where` then you can not update it directly

```
irb(main):039:0> @kit = Kit.where(number: "3456")
Kit Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "kits".* FROM "kits" WHERE "kits"."number" =  
'3456' => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Kit id: 1, number: "3456", 
created_at: "2015-05-12 06:10:56", updated_at: "2015-05-12 07:16:58", 
job_id: 2>]>

irb(main):040:0> @kit.update(job_id: 3)
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)
```

in such a case you would have to specify it like this

```
irb(main):043:0> @kit[0].update(job_id: 3)
(0.2ms)  BEGIN Kit Exists (0.6ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "kits" WHERE 
("kits"."number" = '3456' AND "kits"."id" != 1) LIMIT 1 SQL (0.6ms)   
UPDATE "kits" SET "job_id" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "kits"."id" = 1  
[["job_id", 3], ["updated_at", Tue, 12 May 2015 07:28:04 UTC +00:00]]
(0.5ms)  COMMIT => true
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for

Comment: @kit = Kit.where(number: "3456").first   -

This lets you update it directly and it's safer since it survived deprecation

Answer (score 8):

Apart from accepted answer, following is also valid

`Model.find()` can accept array of ids, and will return all records which matches.
`Model.find_by_id(123)` also accept array but will only process first id value present in array

```
Model.find([1,2,3])
Model.find_by_id([1,2,3])
```

Answer (score 8):

The answers given so far are all OK.

However, one interesting difference is that `Model.find` searches by id; if found, it returns a `Model` object (just a single record) but throws an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` otherwise.

`Model.find_by` is very similar to `Model.find` and lets you search any column or group of columns in your database but it returns `nil` if no record matches the search.

`Model.where` on the other hand returns a `Model::ActiveRecord_Relation` object which is just like an array containing **all the records that match the search**. If no record was found, it returns an empty `Model::ActiveRecord_Relation` object.

I hope these would help you in deciding which to use at any point in time.

Answer (score 7):

Suppose I have a model `User`

1. `User.find(id)`

Returns a row where primary key = id. The return type will be `User` object.

2. `User.find_by(email:"abc@xyz.com")`

Returns first row with matching attribute or email in this case. Return type will be `User` object again.

Note :- `User.find_by(email: "abc@xyz.com")` is similar to `User.find_by_email("abc@xyz.com")`

3. `User.where(project_id:1)`

Returns all users in users table where attribute matches.

Here return type will be `ActiveRecord::Relation` object. `ActiveRecord::Relation` class includes Ruby's `Enumerable` module so you can use it's object like an array and traverse on it.

Answer (score 5):

Both #2s in your lists are being deprecated. You can still use `find(params[:id])` though.

Generally, `where()` works in most situations.

Here's a great post: https://web.archive.org/web/20150206131559/http://m.onkey.org/active-record-query-interface

Comment: great post doesn't exist.

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20150206131559/http://m.onkey.org/active-record-query-interface

Answer (score 1):

Since Rails 4 you can do:

```
User.find_by(name: 'Bob')
```

which is the equivalent `find_by_name` in Rails 3.

Use `#where` when #find and `#find_by` are not enough.

Answer (score 0):

The best part of working with any open source technology is that you can inspect length and breadth of it.
[Checkout this link](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb)

find_by ~> Finds the first record matching the specified conditions. There is no implied ordering so if order matters, you should specify it yourself. If no record is found, returns nil.

find ~> Finds the first record matching the specified conditions , but if no record is found, it raises an exception but that is done deliberately.

Do checkout the above link, it has all the explanation and use cases for the following two functions.

Answer (score -6):

I will personally recommend using

```
where(< columnname> => < columnvalue>)
```

Comment: This may answer the question. But try describing the pros and cons of using your approach, instead of the accepted answer.