# Why am i getting a NoMethodError on this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-routing

I have this in my `config/routes.rb`:

```
get '/:category/:region', to: 'categories#filtered_by_region'
```

The `filtered_by_region` action is as shown below:

```
#filtered_by_region method
def filtered_by_region
  @region = Region.where(title: params[:region]).first
  @category = Category.where(title: params[:category]).first
  @teams = Team.where(region_id: @region.id, category_id: @category.id)
end
```

I have a view `filtered_by_region.html.erb` that looks as follows:

```
Region: <%= @region.title %>
Category: <%= @category.title %>

<% @teams.each do |team|%>
  <%=team.title %>
<% end %>
```

`region.rb` model is as follows:

```
class Region < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :teams
  attr_accessible :title
end
```

`category.rb` model is as follows:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :teams
  attr_accessible :title
end
```

`team.rb` model is as shown below

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :region
end
```

I also have the corresponding `regions`, `teams` and `categories` tables already populated with data.

when i enter a url that looks like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/football/south_west
```

i get an error with the following message:
``` undefined method ``title' for nil:NilClass ``` I have realized both the `@region` and `@category` are returning nil but i do not understand why. i do have a category with `football` title and a region with `south_west` title in categories and regions tables respectively.

Comment: please specify file and line number where the error came from

Comment: We can't help you based on what you've posted. Your real question is "Why isn't my region/category being found?" and you haven't posted anything that could help us tell you. Open a rails console and make sure you can find the records.

Comment: @meagar when i run the rails console, i can get both the region and category. For instance when i do: category = Category.where(title: 'football').first : i get  Category Load (31.2ms)  SELECT categories`.* FROM categories WHERE categories.title = 'football' ORDER BY title LIMIT 1 => #<Category id: 12, title: "football", created_at: "2013-04-19 10:47:07", updated_at: "2013-05-26 18:43:46"> `

Comment: @meager I am not sure whether this helps but when i check the server log, there is no db query being performed. There is no query that should fetch `@region`, `@category` or `@teams`. the application just renders the view.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [find_by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11161663/find-vs-find-by-vs-where) (if you're using Rails 4) or [find_by_title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11161663/find-vs-find-by-vs-where) (if you're using Rails 3):

```
def filtered_by_region
   @category = Category.find_by_title(params[:category])
   @region = Region.find_by_title(params[:title])

   if defined?(@category) && defined?(@region)
       @teams = Team.where(region_id: region.id, category_id: category.id)
   else
       redirect_to root_path
   end
end
```

I think the likely issue will either be your query is not finding any records, or you'll be trying to access a collection as a record (regardless of the use of `.first`)

Comment: I have tried find_by but it still not working, I've realized that the problem is not that the query is not finding any records but that the query is not being fired at all. When i check the server log, the application just renders the view without trying to find the `@category`, `@region` or `@teams`

Comment: Very strange. Are you sure it's hitting that controller action? Could be an issue with your routes?

Comment: Thank you very much, i had made a careless mistake of not closing the method above the `filtered_by_region` method. The application could therefore not find the action hence rendering the view without hitting the action. Your suggestion helped alot.