# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in BookController#list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to ruby as well as rails I am getting the following error when i open the localhost link /book/list

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in BooksController#list
            Couldn't find Book with 'id'=all
class BookController < ApplicationController
def list
    @books = Book.find(:all) <------- problem is here
  end
  def show
    @book = Book.find(params[:id])
```

My books_controller.rb file.

```
class BookController < ApplicationController
def list
    @books = Book.find(:all)
  end
  def show
    @book = Book.find(params[:id])
  end
  def new
    @book = Book.new
    @subjects = Subject.find(:all)
  end
  #  private 
  def book_params
    params.require(:book).permit(:title,:price,:subject,:description)
  end
  def create
    @book = Book.new(book_params)
    if @book.save
      redirect_to :action => 'list'
    else
      @subjects = Subject.find(:all)
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
  def edit
    @book = Book.find(params[:id])
    @subjects = Subject.find(:all)
  end

  def book1_params
    params.require(:book).permit(:id)
  end

  def update
#below is the line I am getting the error....
@book = Book.find(params[:id])

if @book.update_attributes(book_params)
    redirect_to @book
else
    @subjects = Subject.all
render 'edit'
 end
end

end
```

The @books = Book.find(:all) line in the list method tells Rails to search the books table and store each row it finds in the @books instance object.I am getting error in the list,new and all the nearly all the options.It says that couldnt find book with 'id'=all.

my list.html.erb file.

```
<% if @books.blank? %>
<p>There are not any books currently in the system.</p>
<% else %>
<p>These are the current books in our system</p>
<ul id="books">
<% @books.each do |c| %>
<li><%= link_to c.title, {:action => 'show', :id => c.id} -%></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
<% end %>
<p><%= link_to "Add new Book", {:action => 'new' }%></p>
```

My routes.rb file

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
get 'book/new'
post 'book/create'
post 'book/update'
get 'book/list'
get 'book/show'
get 'book/edit'
get 'book/delete'
get 'book/update'
get 'book/show_subjects'
```

end

I have recently started working with it and i m at the initial stage any help is appreciated.

Comment: what version of `rails`?  You should use `@books = Book.all`

Comment: i am using 4.1.8...Your solution just solved my problem..i was at it for the past 3 hours..thanks alot..

Comment: Are you using an ancient Rails2 tutorial by chance? If you are, you might want to start again with something a bit more modern.

Comment: @soldiershin Whatever tutorial you're using, abandon it. `find(:all)` hasn't been the right way of finding all records in years.

Comment: i was specially following the one at the tutorialpoint bcz usually they have some decent material there but now i know..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.find()` method takes a primary key as its argument. When you pass `Book.find(:all)`, your app is attempting to find an instance of `Book` with an id of "all," hence the error message you are seeing.

As Anthony points out, you should be using `Book.all` to return all instances of `Book.`
You can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11161663/find-vs-find-by-vs-where) as a reference when trying to search through your model instances in the future.

Comment: thanks for the answer yes i have abandoned the tutorial and now following the one with the latest rails version..cheers