# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find EmployeeResignation with 'id'=

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I click on print button again and again it through an Active Record error

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find EmployeeResignation with 'id'=):   app/controllers/exit_interviews_controller.rb:67:in `print_exit_interview'



ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find EmployeeResignation with 'id'=
```

My Controller Code -

```
def print_exit_interview
    @employee = params[:exit_interview] ? params[:exit_interview][:employee_id] : params[:employee_id]
    @employee_resignation = EmployeeResignation.find(params[:id])
    @exit_interviews = ExitInterview.where(employee_id: @employee_resignation.employee_id)
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.pdf do
        render :pdf => 'print_exit_interview',
        layout: '/layouts/pdf.html.erb',
        :template => 'exit_interviews/print_exit_interview.pdf.erb',
        :orientation      => 'Landscape', # default , Landscape
        :page_height      => 1000,
        :dpi              => '300',
        :margin           => {:top    => 20, # default 10 (mm)
                      :bottom => 20,
                      :left   => 20,
                      :right  => 20},
        :show_as_html => params[:debug].present?
      end
    end
  end
```

In routes I have written post :print_exit_interview .

Comment: What are the `params` coming in the server log? Please post those.

Comment: looks like you're relying on `employee_id` everywhere else, why not try that instead of `:id` as a param

Comment: I think the problem is in your this line

`@employee_resignation = EmployeeResignation.find(params[:id])`

Make you sure that id coming for params is valid.

or you can use `@employee_resignation = EmployeeResignation.find_by(id: params[:id])` that will handle exceptions.

Comment: @Anubhi Golechha, use `render json: params and return false` on the first line of method.

Comment: is the issue resolved?

Comment: @AniketShivamTiwari yeah !!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and that error seems correct. You may not have a record in `employee_resignations` table with a blank ID. `params` may not have `id` attribute in it.

If you want to mitigate this error, use `EmployeeResignation.find_by(id: params[:id])` instead. `.find()` throws an error if record is not found in the database. On the other hand, `find_by` will return `nil` if the record is not found with the specified criteria.

A good discussion is available [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11161663/find-vs-find-by-vs-where).

Comment: now it is not giving any error but when I login with different employee_id it is showing the records of previous employee_id .

Comment: @AnubhiGolechha It is a separate issue, and there are many possibilities. May be you're passing previously used employee ID in the route. As @Paven mentioned in the comments, please post what did you receive in `params`.