# How to get active record's name after using find .where

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Straight forward here:

```
                 <% @yyy = CityRace.where(city_race_id2: "3") %> 
                 <% @xxx =  @yyy.name %>
```

The @yyy is returning the proper record using the ID I have passed into it, but I'm trying to get the objects name. For some reason .name isn't working. Any idea what I'm going wrong here?

How do I find a record's name where id = a certain id?

Comment: If CityRace has a name field, and the item with that ID has a name, that should be just fine. What do you see if you just print `@yyy`?

Comment: @Balastrong undefined method `name' for #<CityRace::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x000000000a00e7e0>

Comment: And if you print only `@yyy`? not `@yyy.name`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages. You're asking us to help debug code but didn't provide code that duplicates the problem.

Comment: _"The @yyy is returning the proper record"_ – no, it returns an instance of `ActiveRecord::Relation` which is a proxy to all records (plural) with a `city_race_id2` of `"3"`.

Answer (score 3):

`where` returns an ActiveRecord_Relationship, meaning an object containing CityRace objects for every row in the database with `city_race_id2` equals to 3, no matter if there's only one, the result is an `ActiveRecord_Relationship` object, and that doesn't respond to `name`.

If you need the name of a particular object from that result, you can access to the specific element by its index and invoke `name` on it, e.g:

```
CityRace.where(city_race_id2: "3").first.name
```

Or to retrieve the name from every object:

```
CityRace.where(city_race_id2: "3").pluck(:name)
```

this one returns an array of strings, so, you must iterate over them to print them all or get a specific one.

In the other hand if you need a single row from the query, use `find_by`:

```
CityRace.find_by(city_race_id2: "3").name
```

Answer (score 2):

[`.where`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/where) returns an [`ActiveRecord::Relation`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/where) which behaves like an array. You can think of it like a special kind of array that allows you to chain on more active record queries on it. When you call certain methods like `each` or `to_a` it evaluates the query into an *actual* array.

In any case, what you are looking for here is *not* something array-like. You want `@yyy` to refer to a *single record*.

Simple fix, just use `find_by` instead of `where`. Also take a look at https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find and [find vs find_by vs where](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11161663/find-vs-find-by-vs-where)